# Do babies from the United States cry more then babies in other parts of the world?

Tags: united-states, children, culture

In the Cracked article [*5 Universal Experiences That Are Different In Other Cultures*](http://www.cracked.com/article_24461_5-insane-ways-your-culture-physically-shapes-your-perception.html) the third claim made is that

> American Babies Cry Way More Than Other Babies

I would like to know if the claim is literally true, that American (United States to be exact) babies cry significantly more then babies of all other cultures.

If that is not true then is it true that babies from the United states cry more then children from any or all of culture/locations explicitly called out in the article, specifically Sioux, Kenya, Mexico, and South Korea?

Comment: The cracked article links to https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2005/jun/08/familyandrelationships.features10

Comment: Sheila Kitzinger's book: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Understanding-Your-Crying-Baby-parents/dp/190476021X

Comment: Aren't many cracked articles totally satirical?  As far as I can recall [Cracked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cracked.com) and Cracked.com used to do mostly comedy pieces competing with [Mad Magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_(magazine)).

Comment: @MarkRogers Most Cracked articles are "infotainment" - presented as being based on true facts with the comedy element coming from the tone and how the facts or personal anecodotes are presented. When it's pure satire it's usually made obvious in the headline or lead-in

Comment: @MarkRogers: In addition to user568458's comment, Cracked is also unusually good about citing their sources, or at least linking to them. Unless the links have died, you can generally find out where they got their information.

Comment: Even if Cracked posted these claims in jest, if enough people believe them then there's not much difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [THE CRYING PATTERN OF KOREAN INFANTS AND RELATED FACTORS](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1469-8749.1994.tb11897.x/abstract) *Developmental Medicine & Child Neurology*, volume 36, pages 565–658 (July 1994):

> Compared with Western studies, the duration of crying of Korean infants was shorter and the time of holding and/or close contact with mothers longer, and colic was not found in this study.